# Is “taken” adjective here?

Tags: adjectives

In this sentence, is “**taken**” adjective?

> The imitation process begins when the collection of fashions is presented by models on catwalk through some of photos **taken** and sent to manufacturers.

Comment: @Jason Bassford I have edited the sentences.

Comment: I still don't understand what's being described. You added a sentence for additional context, but the original sentence still doesn't make sense to me. Is it pictures of catwalks that are displayed a collection of some kind? Is it a collection of catwalk pictures? What does *through some of the photos* mean?

Comment: This would make sense to me: *When the collection **of taken photos** is presented on catwalks.* If that's what's meant, then *taken* serves the same syntactic function as *stolen*, and the sense of *taken* is "photos removed from somewhere," not "photos that were produced." In that construction, and that sense, *taken* is a verb that's functioning adjectivally. But I don't know if that's the intended interpretation.

Comment: Your sentence is distinctly odd, but nevertheless "taken" is a past participle **verb** modifying "photos". Although it's only a single word, it is still analysed as a past-participial clause.

Comment: @Jason Bassford the collection here are fashions which represented by models.

Comment: @Question And what does that have to do with photos? Is it photos *of* models on catwalks? If so, it would be the following: *When the collection of photos (taken) of models on catwalks is presented.* And if the verb is used at all (it doesn't need to be) it would not be acting adjectivally. It would also be the more normal sense of the verb.

Comment: @Joson Bassford the sentence is like “The imitation process begins when the collection of fashions is presented by models on catwalk through some of photos taken and sended to manufacturers.”

Comment: It seems the sentence was written by you. You cannot have have read this anywhere, as it is ungrammatical and confusing. Before knowing if "taken" is an adjective or not, you should know that the verb "send" is irregular.

Answer (score 1):

BillJ:

Your sentence is distinctly odd, but nevertheless "taken" is a past participle **verb** modifying "photos". Although it's only a single word, it is still analysed as a past-participial clause.

Me:
A past-participle is a modifier that works like an adjective. Some adjectives are past participles that have basically become adjectives, e.g., *the **gone** girl*.

Answer (score 0):

You may think in this way:

> At what moment does the imitation process begin? (The imitation
> process begins) when the collection is presented on catwalks through
> some of the photos taken.

The part inside the parenthesis is omitted.

And now strike the below part to make the meaning of 'taken' clearer.

> The imitation process begins  <strike>when the collection is presented
> on catwalks</strike>  through some of the photos taken.

The 'taken' indicates the action of taking photos at the catwalk and it's a verb. It doesn't mean the photos which were already taken before.

Comment: "The ...process begins ...by models through some photos (that are) taken and sent to manufacturers."  This is the skeletal structure, and I think it is fine. Here, "...taken and sent...." is similar to " of things that are taken and sent to manufacturers - which talk more about photos'. Am I right?